# Can we use server configuration tool for MFP Foundation on IBM Container(Bluemix)?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

Server Configuration Tool needs Database Settings(host,port,username,password,dbname) and AppServer Settings(installation directory,username,password) information. The tool also need to access database directly.

The MFPF docs doesn't provide such kind of information. Is there anyway to user server configuration tool for MFPF on ibm container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use the Server configuration tool for IBM Containers deployment. The only current way is to use the scripts as provided and instructed, here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/bluemix/run-foundation-on-bluemix/